# Android HLS plays first segment then only audio

Tags: android, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I'm having difficulty playing HLS on Android where only the audio is playing. The stream will play for the first video segment and then turn into an audio only stream. Here is a sample link https://clipter.com/c/aymels8/hls.m3u8

**hls.m3u8**

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:9
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXTINF:8.5,
https://d3ilpkc014v0xn.cloudfront.net/f5305de24/2103cb31c3078eb5edd5c325108f6d6f.ts?1416176849
#EXTINF:7.33,
https://d3ilpkc014v0xn.cloudfront.net/f5305de24/1214ef63a031e3d3229893fdb60eea86.ts?1416176848
#EXTINF:8.5,
https://d3ilpkc014v0xn.cloudfront.net/f5305de24/99c47c49548521b0fff05119a5c63908.ts?1416176889
#EXTINF:8.43,
https://d3ilpkc014v0xn.cloudfront.net/f5305de24/143acefc2149f2572ddcc08abb705736.ts?1416176988
#EXTINF:4.43,
https://d3ilpkc014v0xn.cloudfront.net/f5305de24/11c92b5084971e0cf4768f958e97f936.ts?1416177431
#EXTINF:6.9,
https://d3ilpkc014v0xn.cloudfront.net/f5305de24/10ab810169fb684469f736a53f2cba3a.ts?1416177545
#EXTINF:8.57,
https://d3ilpkc014v0xn.cloudfront.net/f5305de24/88b037af27757e4805d7f1ed0496cbb8.ts?1416178434
#EXTINF:2.1,
https://d3ilpkc014v0xn.cloudfront.net/f5305de24/4a8cda13ea40228de4638dee9985b8b0.ts?1416178513
#EXTINF:8.47,
https://d3ilpkc014v0xn.cloudfront.net/f5305de24/e6fa0135987c86d323f1e994bcd2b429.ts?1416179772
#EXTINF:8.38,
https://d3ilpkc014v0xn.cloudfront.net/f5305de24/9a08aba19b45601c83854216bb07a6b6.ts?1416604373
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

**output from ffprobe**

```
ffprobe version 2.3.3 Copyright (c) 2007-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Aug 25 2014 19:47:15 with Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.3.3 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --enable-vda --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libx264 --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libxvid
  libavutil      52. 92.100 / 52. 92.100
  libavcodec     55. 69.100 / 55. 69.100
  libavformat    55. 48.100 / 55. 48.100
  libavdevice    55. 13.102 / 55. 13.102
  libavfilter     4. 11.100 /  4. 11.100
  libavresample   1.  3.  0 /  1.  3.  0
  libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
  libswresample   0. 19.100 /  0. 19.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mpegts, from '2103cb31c3078eb5edd5c325108f6d6f.ts?1416176849':
  Duration: 00:00:08.53, start: 1.400000, bitrate: 1236 kb/s
  Program 1 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg
    Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p, 480x480, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x101](und): Audio: aac ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 67 kb/s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved by adding the #EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY tag after each url. The reason the audio kept playing and the video stopped is because each video segment had the same start time 1.4(unfortunately a value I cannot change in my application). See https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-13 for more detail